# Why do they never turn the gravity off?

Tags: star-trek, artificial-gravity

In Star Trek it seems that they almost always have artificial gravity. The idea of not having it is shocking, even though my 21st century mind relates it directly with space.  Here are a few examples:

- Deep Space 9 episode Melora, Dr. Bashir shows wonder and amazement at being in a low gravity environment. (He'd really never been outside artificial gravity?)
- In the Star Trek VI, when the Klingon's gravity is disabled, they even refer to themselves as being helpless. (They never trained for this?)
- In the TNG episode Ethics, Worf gets severely injured because something like a barrel, fell on him in the cargo-bay. (Couldn't the gravity be reduced in the cargo bay at least?)
- In the TNG episode Hollow Pursuits, Barclay has problems with his anti-gravity device. (Why not just switch the artificial gravity off?)

The only explanation I can think is that for some reason artificial gravity is required for space travel, but is there any canonical explanation for why they cling so doggedly to gravity?

I'm looking for an in universe explanation. I'm also curious why the gravity generators are rarely targeted, but that may be another question.

Comment: Why *would* they turn it off? Low gravity makes everything so much more challenging

Comment: Really? _Everything_? I think that that is clearly not true.

Comment: Well, floating around the ship would be harder. But low-g makes it harder to eat, drink, sleep, work, navigate the ship, use the toilet, brush your teeth, bathe,... Not to mention the consequences to your health

Comment: Gravity seems like something that may be very difficult to control in individual locations. If you had gravity "on" in one room, it would affect adjacent rooms that were at "0 gravity", so things would be pulled to the left/right instead of down. Since it's likely all-or-nothing, I'd imagine that since they often need gravity it's always going to be on.

Comment: The individual gravity generators keep working for 240 minutes without power, according to the technical manual, making them a very poor target during an assault

Comment: @GorchestopherH According to [Gravity - Memory Alpha](http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity), "While training a crew of former Maquis, Tuvok increased the gravity on certain decks aboard the USS Voyager by 10% during their exercise run." So apparently localized adjustments are possible, though I have no idea to what extent.

Comment: It's out-of-universe rather than canon, but zero-g causes a lot of problems for human biology, both short-term (sickness, disorientation, etc) and long-term (loss of muscle and bone density, circulatory problems, etc).  In a world where artificial gravity is commonplace and easy, zero-g operations are likely quite rare, if not actively discouraged for medical reasons.

Comment: It's all relative. In southeast Texas, we almost NEVER turn the A/C off, yet to someone 200 years ago the very IDEA of A/C was preposterous. Just sayin'...

Comment: @Daniel Cook And in First Contact Worf is severely not cool with the space walk on the Enterprise's hull.

Comment: Breaking the fourth wall. It's a whole lot harder to film and make it look like there's no gravity, but this is the opposite of an in-universe explanation.

Comment: The Enterprise-D has variable gravity areas in the shuttle bays (as indicated by warnings on the floor/walls).

Comment: Federation Ships also use Gravity plates -- http://en.memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Gravity_plate

Comment: 1 theory- due to the effects of long term weightlessness that Nerrolken pointed out, could artificial gravity be considered part of life support?

Comment: In the original series, we frequently heard "Gravity is down to .8" in the background.

Comment: I would totally expect the Klingons as well as the Federation (and really, probably every ship with a warp drive) to drill frequently for loss of artificial gravity. Drills are a fact of military life, and on any ship, those drills are all about every possible thing that can go wrong (especially in combat), and fixing it ASAP. It's laughable that the crew would be helpless under these circumstances, nevermind not being able to fix the problem in a very short period of time.

Comment: In my opinion, while Star Trek takes place in space (mainly), it is not a space-oriented show. The main focus of the plot is interpersonal behavior. How to behave towards strangers, how to deal with differing opinions, or how to overcome an enemy without breaking your moral code. Your question (while a valid question!) is the equivalent of focusing on the applied traffic law in a road trip movie.

Comment: @Valorum To me, that sounds like what would happen if the machinery itself is intact but powerless, rather than damaged.  Of course, us not knowing how it works doesn't help.

Comment: @Flater Various quotes of Roddenberry bear that out.  I think anyone who expects or inspects Star Trek for exploration or satisfaction of the physical and so–called _hard sci-fi_ aspect is going to be disappointed.

Comment: I wonder if naval submarines sometimes turn the air off.

Comment: @GorchestopherH: "Gravity seems like something that may be very difficult to control in individual locations." - I think this is directly contradicted by the episode cited in the question, DS9: "Melora", where the eponymous character switches to low-g in a single room.

Comment: @Flater: I don't think that is a valid objection. You could say the same about technical questions such as "Is there a trick to circumvent a ship's shields?", "What can go wrong with warp drive?", "Does interior lighting fail in powerless ships?", etc., and no matter how much ST focuses on interpersonal behaviour, all of these technical questions have been abundantly brought up and/or answered in individual episodes. Seeing how this includes technologies from the very futuristic (e.g. transporter) to the "normal" ones (lights), the omission of artificial gravity is indeed a striking exception.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Chekhov's Gun applies. Artifical gravity would be mentioned if it were to cease working at some point, which leads the plot down an avenue that Star Trek tends not to go down. That is not a people-oriented problem.

Comment: @Flater: As I said, issues with the warp drive, the transporter, the ship's computer, the ship's interior lights, etc., are not inherently "people-oriented" problems, either.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Would that not be a good explanation as to why the cited circumstance was indeed surprising?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- In [TOS: The Doomsday Machine](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Doomsday_Machine_%28episode%29), we see a crippled, nearly
  destroyed USS Constellation. The gravity still works.
- In [TNG: Booby Trap](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Booby_Trap_%28episode%29), we see a ship which has been in an energy draining environment for centuries. The gravity still works.
- In [ENT: Broken Bow](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Broken_Bow_%28episode%29), we see Mayweather exploiting Enterprise's "sweet spot": a section of the ship where the overall gravity configuration demands an area where gravity is reversed. He says "all ships have one."

This would seem to indicate that artificial gravity is a low power system, difficult to disable, and finicky to configure. Bear in mind that Qo'noS One was hit at point blank range with her shields down by a commander who knew her systems intimately; this is not common battlefield damage. In universe, this forms a solid rationale for gravity hi-jinks being rare.

Comment: Enterprise was a Holodeck game tho'; the "sweet spot" thing could have just been a made-up plot device.

Comment: YOU'RE a holodeck game! ;-)

Comment: @Gaius: pfft....

Comment: Also gravity in TOS: Space Seed aboard the Botany Bay. - Which makes no sense, considering it is way pre-warp. and presumably before "gravity plating."

Comment: It seems that gravity plating, or a working predecessor, was in operation well pre-warp. See also, TNG: The Neutral Zone.

Comment: It seems that artificial gravity works at least per deck (VOY:Prototype, VOY:Prey) and somewhere in Voyager they were having training for something and increased gravity on one deck. I don't think it is hard to tinker with it, its just that nobody thinks of it. I think in  TNG there was some episode where someone required lower gravity and had a suite or so

Comment: @PlasmaHH It was DS9, some female science visitor Dr. Bashir flirted with.

Comment: The TNG Tech manual says on p. 144 that gravity is created by a system of generators that have a "superconducting stator" which only requires occasional energy pulses (they give a figure of once per hour) from the [electro-plasma system (EPS)](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Electro-plasma_system) that channels energy from the ship's main reactor(s) to various subsystems. So in the case of derelict ships, we could imagine that before beaming people over, it's part of the standard protocol to beam some pulses of electro-plasma energy into gravity generators to restart them.

Comment: Also, the Federation has all kinds of localized gravity-manipulating technology including tractor beams (said on p. 89 of the TNG tech manual to 'emply superimposed subspace/graviton force beams'), so it's possible that when they come across a ship whose gravity system can't be restarted or that never had one in the first place (which could be the case with the ancient space capsule in "The Neutral Zone"), they might be able to impose a gravitational field on it from the outside before beaming aboard.